# How to append a query string to pagination?

Tags: loop, pagination, variables, query-string, query-variable

I would like to append 2 variables from page 2 onwards in my loop.

**This is my normal category page**

```
www.example.com/category/news/
```

**This is what I would like on pages: 2, 3, 4, 5 etc**

```
www.example.com/category/news/page/2/?var1=one&var2=two
```

The Loop:

```
$args = array
(
   'category_name' => 'news',
   'posts_per_page' => 5,
   'paged' => $paged
);

$news_loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($news_loop->have_posts()) : $news_loop->the_post();

    // posts

endwhile;
wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $news_loop)); ?>
```

Comment: You haven't included the code that actually creates the links? That is a strange thing to leave out.

Comment: um, it's bog standard links created with the wp pagenavi plugin. I have added anywho.

Comment: "Pagenavi" is a ___plugin___ and hence is not "standard"-- common maybe, but not standard. How did you expect anyone to know that this involved a plugin?

Comment: Jesus... It's the same as using 'previous post link', the pagination is not the problem!

Comment: First: [Be nice.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) Second: The plugin creates the links. Maybe it's even responsible for creating rewrite structures. In short: Please [edit] your question and add a link to the plugin source. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this: [Paginate Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

I can see that you are using custom query so you put this below and outside the while loop

```
<?php
        global $wp_query;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        $args = array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?page=%#%',
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged') ),
            'show_all' => true,
            'end_size' => 1,
            'mid_size' => 2,
            'prev_next' => False,
            'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'),
            'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
            'type' => 'list',
            );
        echo paginate_links($args);
    ?>
```